# Best tool for transforming html in a lightweight markup language .NET application?

Tags: html, .net

I have a .NET aplication .

I want to transform a .doc in a lightweight markup language( bbcode, wiki, i don't use others ) .

Till now i used [GemBox.Document](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/articles/c-sharp-vb-net-convert-html-to-word) to convert from .doc in html.

Which is the best lightweight markup language i can use ?

Is there a statistic like : bbCode can process 65% of html tags and wiki mark-up 75% ?

I can't find that( the leaks for every language like this ) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend Markdown.

Check out the .NET implementations

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888985/what-markdown-c-sharp-library-should-i-use